# How to store in a variable an echo | cut result?

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

for example

```
    echo "filename.pdf" | cut -d'.' -f 1
```

This way I get the "filename" string.
I'd like to store it in a variable called FILE and then use it like this:

```
    DIR=$PATH/$FILE.txt
```

So, my script wants to create a file.txt with the same name of the pdf (not a copy of the file, just the name)
This way I tried to assign the result of echo | cut

```
   FILE=
```

but I get only "path/.txt" so the filename is missing.

Comment: `FILE=\`echo "filename.pdf" | cut -d'.' -f 1\``

Comment: ``FILE=`basename filename.pdf .pdf` ``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
FILE=$(echo "filename.pdf" | cut -d'.' -f 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

> So, my script wants to create a file.txt with the same name of the pdf

You can use BASH string manipulation:

```
s="filename.pdf"
p="${s/%.pdf/.txt}"

echo "$p"
filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

POSIX parameter expansion would read

```
file=filename.pdf
filename="${file%%.*}"  # Two % will remove multiple extensions, if applicable
dir=$path/$filename.txt
```